# Laravel Sub-subdomain

Tags: laravel, nginx, vagrant, subdomain, laravel-5.3

I've been trying to get my head around this all day. I understand how to create and manage single level subdomains in laravel, such as `subdomain.domain.com`

However, I'm trying to add a second level subdomain, for example: `subsubdomain.subdomain.domain.com`

I can get Homestead working fine with single level subdomains, but whenever I add the extra subdomain, I get a connection refused - unable to connect error in chrome.

There's nothing in the nginx error log either.

This is what I've done:

1. Open `~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml
2. Add the domain `subsubdomain.subdomain.domain.com` in addition to `subdomain.domain.com`
3. Save and exit, then run `vagrant reload --provision`
4. I can see the new sub-subdomain added to the hosts file, as well as a conf file created in the vagrant box
5. When I try to access `subdomain.domain.com` it works fine, when I try to access `subsubdomain.subdomain.domain.com` it fails with `refused to connect`.

I have no idea what to try next, there's nothing in the nginx error log, Homestead is up and running because I can access the single level subdomain completely fine. The only one that isn't working is the second level subdomain.

Any info on what I might be doing wrong, or anything else that might be helpful to debug would be greatly appreciated.

#### Update

I've managed to connect to the server if I add the port `:8000` to the address: `subsubdomain.subdomain.domain.com` doesn't work, but `subsubdomain.subdomain.domain.com:8000` works